# Jenkins on Windows no web GUI - can't setup

Tags: jenkins, windows-2003-webserver

Ive installed Jenkins on a Win2003 Server but when the install completes and attempts to load up the GUI in the browser it fails with a "Internet explorer cannot display this webpage message".

I've uninstalled and re-installed it several times, rebooted, re-installed the latest java but still no luck!

Hopefully someone can shed some light on what to try next or maybe even solve it.

---

MORE INFO:

I installed it a long time ago as a service and it was working. But the it then got put on the backburner and so was disabled. Its now wanted by the boss man so I went to the localhost and it gave the error even with the service restarted.

I then tried to stop the service again and services.msc threw up so error but with no details of note. So, I then disabled the service.

I rebooted and reinstalled it several times, and installed the latest JAVA update and still no luck.

On one occasion I managed to get the web GUI to start and then a message came up saying it was waiting for Jenkins to start up. After a period of waiting this timed out and IE returned the cannot find page error/message.

Ive tried reinstalling / uninstalling / rebooting / etc but nothing seems to make a difference.

---

Recent block from the Jenking.err.log:

Nov 28, 2013 2:55:20 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info

INFO: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT

Nov 28, 2013 2:55:28 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info

INFO: Extract jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Jenkins/jenkins.war!/ to C:\WINDOWS\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jenkins.war--any-\webapp

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:15 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info

INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:16 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info

INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:16 PM winstone.Logger logInternal

INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:17 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained

INFO: Started initialization

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:21 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained

INFO: Listed all plugins

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:22 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained

INFO: Prepared all plugins

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:22 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained

INFO: Started all plugins

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:22 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained

INFO: Augmented all extensions

Nov 28, 2013 2:56:22 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained

INFO: Loaded all jobs

Comment: Did you install Jenkins as a service or just as a console application? And did you see anything in the Jenkins error log (jenkins.err.log in the install directory)

Comment: @Petrik Please see my updated question for the relevant info and log stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Comparing your logs to our own it seems Jenkins is not starting the http listener. Ours is started just after the extraction from the WAR file. The log file doesn't directly indicate why, but you might check that the port Jenkins wants to use is actually available. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins for more info on specifying a TCP port when running jenkins.

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused the problem? Would be interested in knowing if my guess was correct.

Comment: @Petrik Thanks for the follow-up, I'd forgotten about this as its not currently needed and Im not sure how I would go about testing the port. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Two options I see are: a) just change the Jenkins port to something that is unlikely to be used (e.g. 5050 or something) and see if it connects (from the logs). If so then it was a port problem, if not then you have another problem. Or you could do a port scan of some kind to find open ports. This [page](http://surf11.com/entry/176/command-to-show-open-tcp-ports-windows) suggests using `netstat -anop TCP` which should give you all the connected ports for TCP. Adding a `b` to the command list gives you the application names as well.

Comment: @Petrik Thanks for the suggestions. Ill take a look as soon as time allows and then get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience once I saw that I couldn't navigate to localhost:8080 I just assumed it was a  server issue. Given that I use WAMP on my Win 8 machine, I simply turned WAMP off...and it worked. Naturally this isn't ideal and when I figure out how to redirect a request from port 80 to 8080, I'll update my answer